# How to replace same text in a text file

Tags: c#, .net, io, replace, text-files

i created a c# windows login form and i am saving username or password to a text file but every time when i use same username or password that i have saved before it takes  new place in that text file.

But What i want is to replace the same username or password that is already saved in that text file.

this is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.Append,
            FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.Write("Email ID: ");
            sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            sw.Write("Password: ");
            sw.Write(textBox2.Text);
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Close();
        }
            MessageBox.Show("DONE", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why replace it? Just do nothing when you already have them in the file. I have done a little modification to your code. Look into this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string file= File.ReadAllText("data.txt");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.Append,
        FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        if(file.Contains(textBox1.Text+"\r\n"+textBox2.Text);
        {
           //Do nothing if you already have them in the file
        }
        else
        {
          sw.WriteLine("Email ID: "+textBox1.Text);
          sw.Write("Password: "+textBox2.Text);
          sw.WriteLine();
          sw.WriteLine();
        }
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        this.Close();
    }
        MessageBox.Show("DONE", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
}
```

Comment: But I donot understand why its username or password as in your question. Since you are not using a database which you should actually be working with here, you should bind the username and password as one in the text file. Separate each user's name and password with some symbol like `@`, and later you can compare the login credentials and do any modifications. I dont think its a good idea comparing only username or password to replace them.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the username in the text file, and if it exists you can edit the password..
but u better use a database for this :)

Answer (score 0):

first search for the same username i.e read whole file for searching by using method 'File.ReadAllText', u can search by comparing username text with file text.
once u got the username, calculate or get position of that username text by using inbuilt functions of c#, then move ur write pointer to username text, & replace it.